# Closing buffer when changing files with NerdTree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, lsp, plugin-tabnine

I am using `NVIM v0.7.2` on Arch Linux. Right now I got a problem with the plugins `vim-easycomplete` and `nerdtree`.

When I operate on one file and open another one, the first file stays in the buffer. On usual occasion, this wouldn't be a problem because I would move back and forth between the files when working on project. In my case as I'm doing the `rust-lang/rustlings`-course right now, I finish a task and continue with the next one, so after some time I got several buffers open.

The problem is that with each buffer because of `vim-easycomplete`, a new instance of `rust-analyzer` (language-server) attaches to a buffer. With several file open and only 8Gigs of RAM available, my memory gets eaten up fastly...

**So my question is**: is there a way to close the when opening a new file with NerdTree?

Thank you for reading!

EDIT: I've observed my memory usage a little more and it turned out that the high memory usage came from multiple instances of `TabNine` which is supported by `vim-easycomplete`. I turned it off with `let g:easycomplete_tabnine_enable = 0` which is a work-around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- List all current buffers: `:buffers`
- Delete all open buffers: `:%bd!`
- Delete a specific buffer: `:bdelete <filename>`
- Delete buffer number 1: `:1bd`
- Delete buffers from ranges 1 to 4: `:1,4bd`

You can also map `` command! BufOnly execute '%bd|edit #|normal `" `` in your `.vimrc` to delete all other buffers except the one you are currently working on. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to know. But it definitely brings me forwards! Thank you!

Comment: @hmaier I apologize if this didn’t help. I hope you end ip finding a solution. Have a good day :D